# Tensor Calculus - How do I derive the formula for change of coordinates of a derivative?

Tags: calculus, tensors

In my textbook I suddenly encountered the formula:
$$ \frac{\partial T_a}{\partial Z^b} = \frac{\partial T_i}{\partial Z^j} J^i_a J^j_b +T_i J^i_{a,b} $$
Where J are jacobians and Z superscript represents coordinates.
I can't quite figure out where $+T_i J^i_{a,b}$ part comes from.

I know the transformation law for any rank tensor but I'm missing an explanation for the derivative change of coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason there are two terms is because of the product rule. We have $T_a = T_iJ^i_a$, so $\dfrac{\partial T_a}{\partial Z^b} = \dfrac{\partial}{\partial Z^b}(T_iJ^i_a) = \dfrac{\partial T_i}{\partial Z^b} J^i_a + T_i\dfrac{\partial J^i_a}{\partial Z^b} = \dfrac{\partial T_i}{\partial Z^j}J^i_aJ^j_b + T_iJ^i_{a,b}$.